# Trying to deploy a Mule4 Policy on Exchange goal deploy-file not found

Tags: mule

I am trying to deploy a custom policy to Exchange, but it results in:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----< 7de36ab5-1c25-4cd4-89e8-ec315f34b341:message-header-policy >-----
[INFO] Building message-header-policy 1.0.3
[INFO] ----------------------------[ mule-policy ]-----------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.446 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-16T15:01:04+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Could not find goal 'deploy-file' in plugin org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.1.6 among available goals clean, compile, deploy, generate-resources, generate-sources, generate-test-resources, generate-test-sources, initialize, package, process-classes, process-resources, process-sources, site, test-compile, undeploy, validate -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoNotFoundException
```

My pom file is:

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>organizationid</groupId>
<artifactId>message-header-policy</artifactId>
<version>1.0.3</version>
<packaging>mule-policy</packaging>

<name>message-header-policy</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <app.runtime>4.1.3</app.runtime>
    <exchange.url>https://maven.eu1.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/organizationid/maven</exchange.url>
    <mule.maven.plugin.version>3.1.6</mule.maven.plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>upload-template</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <repositoryId>Repository</repositoryId>
                        <url>${exchange.url}</url>
                        <file>${project.basedir}/${project.artifactId}.yaml</file>
                        <generatePom>false</generatePom>
                        <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <packaging>yaml</packaging>
                        <classifier>mule-policy</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.anypoint</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-http-policy-transform-extension</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>

<repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
        <name>Anypoint Exchange</name>
        <url>https://maven.eu1.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
        <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>https://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
       <id>Repository</id>
       <name>Corporate Repository</name>
       <url>${exchange.url}</url>
       <layout>default</layout>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

organizationid is the GUID from our organisation ....

I have based this on the documentation found on this page: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/policy-scope-size-concept

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Exchange credentials in maven settings.xml

```
 <servers>
   <server>
   <id>Repository</id>
   <username>myusername</username>
   <password>mypassword</password>
 </server>
```

Hope it helps